# No me funciona <br/> cuando imprimo con Response.text()

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

HTML

```
<p id="p"</p>
```

JS

```
const p = document.getElementById("p");
p.addEventListener("click", z);
function z(){
   fetch(url?q='Hola').then((res) => {
     res.text().then((res) => {
        p.textContent=res;
     })
   })
}
```

PHP

```
echo $_REQUEST["q"]."<br/>Adiós";//Salida 'Hola'<br/>Adiós
```

¿Porqué no hace un salto de línea?¿Cómo puedo hacer para que lo haga? Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reemplaza
textContent por innerHTML

```
  const p = document.getElementById("p");
        p.addEventListener("click", z);

        function z(){
            fetch(url?q="Hola").then((res) => {
                res.text().then((htmlResponse) => {
                    p.innerHTML = htmlResponse;
                });
            });
        }
```